# Background of text full width without css but only html in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background

I would like to get a white background for my parallax scroll on my website.

My text is:

```
<p style="background-color: white; text-align: justify;">Wir bieten (...) gesandt bekommen.</p>
```

I've tried it with `padding`, `background-width` or `background-size`, but nothing worked...

I would like edit the background a bit more (width and height)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
width: 100%;
```

and

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: unfortunatel did not work... I tried width and background-width and both did not work.